# Shel Script [tail] return line no fim de cada fichier concatenado

Tags: shell, unix

Viva,

tenho varios ficheiros com o mesmo headers. o que pretendia é copiar o conteudo de todos os ficheiros para dentro de 1 so mas so com 1 header.

Ja consegui fazer essa parte com o codigo abaixo

```
head -3 $FILE1 > all.csv
tail -n +4 -q *.csv >> all.csv
```

O probleme é que queria mudar de linha depois de cada ficheiro. Com o comando acima ele faz tudo o que quero so que nao muda de linha quando muda de fichiero.

Alguem tem uma idea ?

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo bem curto? Com dois dos `.csv` e com o valor do arquivo descrito em `$FILE1`?

Comment: Esse `tail *.csv >> all.csv` pode gerar alguma encrenca de leitura e escrita no mesmo arquivo (`*.csv` casa com `all.csv`, então `all.csv` aparece como argumento da chamada a `tail`)

Answer (score 0):

Para manipulação de arquivos CSV (também TSV, JSON, etc.) recomendo usar [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`). Este contém *verbos* ou *subcomandos* similares aos bem conhecidos do mundo Unix, como `cat`, `tail`, `cut`, `sort`, etc.

Se os arquivos tem o mesmo "*header*", por ejemplo,

```bash
cat arquivo1.csv
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6

cat arquivo2.csv
a,b,c
7,8,9
```

então o verbo `cat` (de Miller) concatena os conteúdos sem repetir o *header*:

```bash
mlr --csv cat arquivo1.csv arquivo2.csv
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Miller tem uma excelente documentação, para começar, achei legal [Miller em 10 minutos](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/10min/)